# Ansible module to compare files in 2 folder and delete extras

Tags: python, ansible

I have 2 folder one on my server and one on my ansible server and want to make sure that there is no extra files on my server ( such as .bk or files that aren't used anymore ) and be able to exclude files ending with .xyz . Is there a module or a way that this can be done in Ansible or is there a module that can be used. I wont to use cmd or shell tasks but wasn't able to find any module

```
Folder 1 :
Bla.txt
Hello.jar 

Folder 2: 
Bla.txt
Hello.jar
info.log
bla.txt.bk
```

I would like the bla.txt.bk to be delete from the folder 2

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to use [synchronize](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/synchronize_module.html).

"To make sure that there is no extra files" use **delete** parameter, or **rsync_opts** parameter

"To exclude files ending with .xyz" use **rsync_opts** parameter

For example (not tested)

```
- synchronize:
    src: folder_1
    dest: folder_2
    rsync_opts:
      - "--exclude=*.xyz"
      - "--delete"
```

To exclude list of patterns use *--exclude-from=FILE* and [read exclude patterns from FILE](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync).

Comment: Thank you Vladimir, that is a good idea but I have some Template-ing that are happening before so that would mean that the files would be overwritten and if i do it before the templating I would see a lot of changes :(

Comment: An option would be to use -exclude-from=FILE